# How can I find a word in a file without library functions(using read() system call) in C?

Tags: c, buffer, system-calls

I just want to collect a title in a HTML format file.

If I code like this,

```
...
int rd;
char buffer[BUFF_SIZE];
do
{
    rd = read(0, buffer, BUFF_SIZE);
    ...
} while (rd == BUFF_SIZE);
...
```

then I can read a file until EOF anyway, right?

I want to find "〈title〉" in a file, but, suppose that "〈ti" is read in the end of a buffer and "tle〉" is read in the start of the next buffer. In this situation, how can I find "〈title〉"?

Or is there any problem in my reading logic with buffer? Please help me.

Sorry for my bad English. I hope you guys understood.

Comment: You're right, in that way it won't match. Easiest way (with buffered read functions) is to read character by character searching for "<", when you find it you can read 6 characters ("title>") and check for a match. BTW here you're also assuming file is ASCII or UTF8 encoded.

Comment: You could also specially treat the case you mention. If the end of the read buffer matches the beginning of the word you are searching, then you put some bool variable to true, and on the next read if that bool variable is true you check if the rest of the word you are searching matches the beginning of the read buffer.

Comment: Another possibility is reading the whole file into memory. This is an easy solution if the files you want to search are of "reasonable "size (< 100 Mb or so, which is already huge for an html file). On modern computers you have usually more than enough memory for reading a file entirely into memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Adraino mentioned you can read the file character by character.

You just have to recognize `'<'` read the consecutive characters in a temporary array until you encounter `'>'` like this :

```
int ch;
int i = 0;
do
{
  ch=fgetc(file );

  /*file is the file pointer*/
  if(ch=='<')
  {

    while(ch!='>'||ch!=EOF)
    {
      ch=fgetc();
      temp[i]=ch;
      i++;
    }

    temp[i]='\0';
    i=0;
  }

  if(strcmp(temp,"title")==0)

  // read the next characters and store them in a string til '<' is encountered.
  .
  .
} while(ch!=EOF);
```

I hope it helps